# How to make a difference between POST and GET calls in filterchain with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, post, filter, spring-security, get

I searched the internet, but i couldn't find a perfect answer for this question.

I'm making a REST based application with a Spring backend. I make use of a filterchain for authorisation.

There I have 2 different calls (POST and GET) on the same URL,

```
public static final String THINGS_GET = "/rest/things";
public static final String THINGS_REGISTER = "/rest/things";
```

the problem is that only administrators may perform the THINGS_REGISTER call and everyone may perform the THINGS_GET call. 
I can't find a way to define these 2 url's on a different way in my filterchain.

This is my securitycontext.xml with the defined RoleFilters:

```
<beans:bean id="roleEveryoneFilter" class="RoleFilter">
    <beans:property name="userRole" value="EVERYONE"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="roleAdminstratorFilter" class="RoleFilter">
    <beans:property name="userRole" value="ADMIN"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And my filterchain:

```
GET: <filter-chain pattern="/rest/things" filters="roleEveryoneFilter"/>
POST: <filter-chain pattern="/rest/things" filters="roleAdminstratorFilter"/>
```

So how can I make a difference between POST and GET calls in my filterchain or somewhere else?

Comment: what's the reason for using different filter chains?

Comment: There are also other POST and GET calls where i need to make this difference and offcourse I have more filters than these 2, but these filters are not relevant for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us wich version of spring-security you use(maybe post your pom.xml)?
You could give a try in your RoleFilter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if (httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
        // ... do for ADMIN
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else if(httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
        // ... do for Everyone and maybe return without filterChain.doFilter
        //    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

or do it with intercept-url in http element with access="permitAll":

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/things" access="permitAll" method="GET" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/things" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" method="POST" />
</http>
```

Comment: I use spring-security 3.2.5

The first really isn't an option because I have other POST calls which need to be accessed by EVERYONE.

I'll give a try to the second answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: The second answer also isn't the real answer I want. I'll try to find other possibilities on the internet such as method security and such